# How is anaconda installer setting python's sys.prefix?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

With an anaconda's installed python, `sys.prefix` is not set to the [default prefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.prefix), but to a `<conda_install_prefix>`, that is defined at install.
This `<conda_install_prefix>` is not set using a patched `site.py` (or equivalent files), since when moving the python executable out of `<conda_install_prefix>/bin/` (in a place where is has no access to `<conda_install_prefix>`),  is still displayed in the output of `python -m site`

A first intuition: This is directly set in the python executable by the conda installer, (as if the python executable were compiled with the `--prefix` option set), since we can find `<conda_install_prefix>` in the python executable (`strings python | grep <conda_install_prefix>`).
(Then, how does it do this?)